# Python strip() unicode string?

Tags: python, string, unicode, strip

How can you use string methods like strip() on a unicode string? and can't you access characters of a unicode string like with oridnary strings? (ex: mystring[0:4] )

Comment: Have you tried it? `u'asdf   '.strip()[2:]` works perfectly fine for me (it yields `u'df'`).

Comment: So does `u"Hallöle Wélt"[1:5]`.

Comment: Works fine for me. What's your exact problem?

Comment: If one of the answers you got solved your problem, please accept it by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 8):

It's working as usual, as long as they are actually `unicode`, not `str` (note: every string literal *must* be preceded by `u`, like in this example):

```
>>> a = u"coțofană"
>>> a
u'co\u021bofan\u0103'
>>> a[-1]
u'\u0103'
>>> a[2]
u'\u021b'
>>> a[3]
u'o'
>>> a.strip(u'ă')
u'co\u021bofan'
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's a bit late to answer to this, but if you are looking for the library function and not the instance method, you can use that as well.
Just use:

```
yourunicodestring = u'  a unicode string with spaces all around  '
unicode.strip(yourunicodestring)
```

In some cases it's easier to use this one, for example inside a map function like:

```
unicodelist=[u'a',u'   a   ',u' foo is just...foo   ']
map (unicode.strip,unicodelist)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do every string operation, actually in Python 3, all str's are unicode.

```
>>> my_unicode_string = u"abcşiüğ"
>>> my_unicode_string[4]
u'i'
>>> my_unicode_string[3]
u'\u015f'
>>> print(my_unicode_string[3])
ş
>>> my_unicode_string[3:]
u'\u015fi\xfc\u011f'
>>> print(my_unicode_string[3:])
şiüğ
>>> print(my_unicode_string.strip(u"ğ"))
abcşiü
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [Python docs on Unicode strings](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) and the following section on string methods.  Unicode strings support all of the usual methods and operations as normal ASCII strings.