# How can i remove hidden character using python?

Tags: python, unicode, arabic

I have a spatial database (esri geodatabase format) with Arabic characters. The problem is that when I summarize the values, some of the cells that logically should be identical with each other, are different. For example, "اسدی" and "اسدی" should be (and appear to be) indentical, but are not.

There is no white space in begin and end of the names, but when I check the length of the strings, some are 4 and some are 6. The ones that are 6 characters have 2 hidden characters, but I don't see them, and can't find them.

How can I remove the characters with python? I tried to use `rstrip()` and `lstrip()`, but the length remains 6.

Comment: Just a word of caution here: working with Arabic text is no small task.

Comment: Take a look here: [Python strip() unicode string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258411/python-strip-unicode-string)

Comment: or [Stripping non printable characters from a string (incl. unicode)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92438/stripping-non-printable-characters-from-a-string-in-python).

Comment: If Python 2.X, use `repr()` on each string and update your question with the results. If Python 3.X, use `ascii()`. For example, `print(ascii('اسدی'))` returns `'\u0627\u0633\u062f\u06cc'`.  Then you'll see the Unicode codepoints.

Comment: might help if you showed what the characters were

Comment: those two strings are identical and same length. try doing what @MarkTolonen suggests

Comment: Thanks. My friend use sql server and t-sql code. he solve the problem.